# add_action save_post last in execution

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress plugin. I just want to "execute" my add_action('save_post') method the last in all add_action('save_post') chain.

I've got a plugin that clone some post into my blog, My plugin needs to hook this clone event but after cloning to get last post id (clone post id).

I realize that my own add_action('save_post') is executed before add_action('save_post') cloning plugin.

That is not what I want, Is there any posibility to execute my own code after that?

Priority parameter of add_action, is not work for me, there is no execution sorting...

Some ideas???

Thank you!

EDIT: Plugin name: threewp broadcast, I just want to get, with my plugin, new post ID when I broadcast a post from one blog to another in my network (WP multisite). My plugins executes before broadcast, I just want to play my plugin code last one, or, at least, after broadcasting. Is It more clear now? Sorry for my english... Im trying... xD

Comment: Nobody knows? If there is any question about my explanation I'll try to explain better...

Comment: If you put some code , or the name of the cloning plugin, or something more substantial , it might help people to understand better , and also to pinpoint the problem

Comment: Read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116303/66976) link.